# Measure exercise problem covering R^n with closed sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am having a lot of problems trying to do this problem:

> Prove that $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be decomposed into a countable union of the form $$\mathbb{R}^n = N \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B(x_k,r_k)^-$$ where $\lambda(N)=0$ and the closed balls $B(x_,r_k)^-$ are disjoint.

The only thing I have is Lebesgue Measure (in the exercise $\lambda(N)$). Please help.

Comment: Are the balls simply the closures  of standard balls?

Comment: What is the first problem among the "lot of problems" you are having?

Comment: The balls are the clousures of standard balls and for example one of my first problems is that (i don’t know if I am wrong with this but) I am trying to give explicitly the form of the balls, and I am not sure about if that is even posible, or is an “existence” problem. If is an existence problem, I have an idea for $\mathbb{R}$, but I am not sure that is countable.

Comment: Are you allowed to use some covering theorems?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo No, just Lebesgue Measure...